# LWC accordion - multiple variable in a Label within a loop

Tags: lightning-web-components, accordion

I have LWC that loop through data in order to create accordion items
What I am looking to do is to have two variables within the Label.
so something like : {dataItem.locationName} - { dataItem.startDate}

I wanted to do it in the JS but since the loop is in the HTMl I am not sure how to do it ..

HTML:

```
<template for:each={data} for:item="dataItem">
    <div key={dataItem.id}  class="slds-box slds-m-around_xx-small">
        <lightning-accordion-section name={dataItem.id} label= {dataItem.locationName}>
        {dataItem.locationName} - { dataItem.startDate}
    </lightning-accordion-section> 
    </div> 
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prepare data in JS, and later loop through it in HTML.

```js
this.data = someData.map(item => ({
   ...item, //all other properties will be copied.
   locationName: item.fieldToGetLocationName, 
   startDate: item.fieldToGetStartDate
}))
```

Comment: Make sense it is what I was testing ..
thx you